# Hibernate bidirection one to many relation, adding element

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am facing problem with one to many bidirectional relation. I am having problem with adding element B (many) to an A(one). I am trying to add new element in entity.
There is my db schema:
[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL8Fo.png)

There is my A entity:

```
public class Application {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;

@Column(name = "has_paid")
private boolean paid;

@Column(name = "is_accepted")
private boolean accepted;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
private Team team;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Player> players;

public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}
public void addPlayers(Player player){
    System.out.println("---------------1");
    player.setApplication(this);
    System.out.println("---------------2");
    this.players.add(player);
    System.out.println("---------------3");
}
}
```

This is my B entity:

```
public class Player {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Id;

private String name;

private String role;

private String size;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
private Application application;

public Application getApplication() {
    return application;
}

public void setApplication(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}}
```

All the classes have proper getters and setters

My service class:

```
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Override
public Object create(ApplicationsPostDTO applicationsRequest){
    if(Optional.ofNullable(applicationsRequest).isPresent()){
        System.out.println(applicationsRequest.toString());
        Application application = new Application();
        application.setTeam(teamsRepositories.findById(applicationsRequest.getTeam_id()).orElseThrow(BadRequestException::new));
        application.setAccepted(applicationsRequest.isAccepted());
        application.setPaid(applicationsRequest.isPaid());
        System.out.println(application.toString());
        applicationsRequest.getPlayers().forEach(it -> {
            System.out.println(it.toString());
            application.addPlayers(it);

        });
        System.out.println(application.toString());
        return  applicationsRepositories.save(application);
    }else{
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
}
```

Error trace:
[Screen number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGskW.png)

[Screen number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ldm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple npe problem, you forgot to check your `List` for null before adding.

You either check null and instantiate the `List` or add the instatiation directly on the field.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "application", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Now, I am getting stackoverflow. Im trying to add only one player. It seems that something loooping this, and adding over and over the same player [Error stack](https://imgur.com/a/cnVvDDQ)